# rows overlapping on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I map some text, along with an icon (as rows). This works well in iOS but the rows overlap in Android.

```
const criteriaList = [
  { id: 0, title: 'Noor', checked: false },
  { id: 1, title: 'Friends & Grades', checked: false },

];
```

The list is rendered in the `FilterCriteriaList` component.

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
      {criteriaList.map((item: CriteriaList) => (
        <View key={item.id}>
          <View style={styles.criteriaRow}>
            <Icon
              name={item.checked ? 'dot-circle-o' : 'circle-thin'}
              color="#31C283"
              size={moderateScale(20)}/>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  criteriaRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(25),
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  horizontalLine: {
    width: '100%',
    height: moderateScale(1),
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
  text: {
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(15),
    paddingBottom: moderateScale(15),
    marginBottom: moderateScale(15),
    paddingTop: moderateScale(15),
  },
});
```

This is where I am calling the component:

```
        <View style={styles.filterCriteriaContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.greyHeadingText}>Weitere Filter</Text>
          <FilterCriteriaList/>
        </View>


  filterCriteriaContainer: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(35),
    zIndex: 1,
  },
```

**SNACK EXPO:**

https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/rude-pizza

Here as well, it works on the web version but if I try the Android one, the rows overlap.

How can I fix this?

iOS:

[image]

Android
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used flex:1 everywhere which might be the reason for the issue
Try these styles for the list,i kept your code commented in case you need.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // flex: 1,
    //flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  rowContainer: {
    //flex: 1,
    //lineHeight: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  criteriaRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(25),
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingVertical: moderateScale(15),
    //  flex: 1,
  },
  horizontalLine: {
    width: '100%',
    height: moderateScale(1),
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
    //flex:1,
  },
  text: {
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(15),
    //paddingBottom: moderateScale(15),
    //marginBottom: moderateScale(15),
    //paddingTop: moderateScale(20),
    // flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`container` is missing `display: 'flex'`. Then, get rid of `flex: 1` from `container`, `rowContainer`, `criteriaRow`, `horizontalLine`. You're going to need some tinkering to make sure that the text is in line with the icons. I'd suggest getting rid of horizontalLine and instead setting the CSS `borderTop` and `borderBottom` properties. I have tested this on my iPhone.